# Как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения команды удалилось сообщение самой команды?

Tags: python, discord.py

К примеру человек пишет команду **!help**, ему отправляется список команд. Как сделать так чтобы само сообщение от человека (**!help**) удалилось?

Answer (score 2):

`ctx.message.delete()` в самой команде.
Вот [ссылка](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=delete#discord.Message.delete) на документация

Comment: @Sherrix, если это ответ на ваш вопрос, то можете поставить галочку у ответа, чтобы ответ был засчитан.

Comment: Немного не понял, куда это вставлять, вот код:


@client.command()
async def send(ctx,* arg):
    await ctx.send(" ".join(arg))


я просто новичок в этой теме, был бы благодарен если бы подсказали

Comment: а, я понял, спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, поставьте галочку около ответа, чтобы вопрос был засчитан.